# Command getting fail of Device tracking

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to use OS detecting code using a library found here [mobiledetect.net](http://mobiledetect.net/) . But I don't know why command is failing all time. This code works like that if the user come from android OS then it will detect by `$os = 'android'` function. But with this code we can't detect anything and user automatically detect Desktop. Which is mention in last of this code which prove code is failing and at the end, user detecting only desktop. Somehow there is some bug in my coding? could you guys check please?

```
 if( $detect->isMobile() )  {

    if( $detect->isAndroidOS() ) {
        $os = 'android';
    }

    if( $detect->isiOS() ){
        $os = 'iphone';
    }

    if( $detect->isBlackBerryOS() ){
        $os = 'blackberry';
    }

    if( $detect->isPalmOS() ){
        $os = 'palmos';
    }

    if( $detect->isiOS() ){
        $os = 'ipad';
    }

    if( $detect->isBlackBerryOS() ){
        $os = 'blackberry_playbook';
    }

    if( $detect->isWindowsMobileOS() ){
        $os = 'windows_mobile';
    } else
        $os = 'wap';

} else
$os = 'desktop';

return $os;
```

Comment: Bad syntax: your `else` are missing opening/closing curly braces `{}`

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: cury braces not working :(

Comment: My uppar command is failing and and user detetc os desktop only

Comment: are you including/requiring the library and are you instantiating the `$detect` object like this: `require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;` ?

Comment: Could you give me your skype id ? we can discuss regarding full project. Paid.

Comment: email me here, and we will exchange information: lokazo8@yahoo.com